# Java String to JavaScript String Array for Checkbox Checking

Tags: java, javascript, checkbox

I'd like to convert a String array from server to a client String, using no JSON or external lib.
The server side, converts a `String[] xArray = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" }` to `"1, 2, 3"` for client rendering.
The following JavaScript function is responsible for parsing the server String and comparing checkboxes to array values. When it matches, the correspondent checkbox must be checked.

```
function loadCheckBoxes() {         
    var ids = '<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("idsFromServer") %>';      
    if (ids != null && ids !== '') {            
        var idsArray = String.valueOf(ids).indexOf(',') == -1 ? [ids] : ids.split(',');
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('gridIds');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            var index = idsArray.indexOf(checkboxes[i].value);
            if (index >= 0) {
               var foundId = idsArray[index];        
                if (checkboxes[i].value == foundId) {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axcdnt/mjvLd/9/) for tests execution.

**The expected result:** after splitting my array, the correspondent checkboxes must be checked.

Comment: Your code sample differs from the linked JSFiddle... The code in your post works great: http://jsfiddle.net/mjvLd/16/

Comment: @mellamokb the fiddle actually doesn't work. Please check the comments. For the not working solution, it should check "9" and "133" checkboxes.

Comment: No I mean it is functionally different.  There is a bug in the JSFiddle code that is not present in your posted code.  In the JSFiddle, you use `ids[index]` which returns an index of the string, rather than the split array.  But that is correct in your code sample above, because you store the split array in a separate variable, `idsArray`.  If you're going to provide a demo, it needs to use the same code.

Comment: JSFiddle does not accept jsp code (scriptlets, EL, etc). Do you agree? The above code is what I really use in my code while the jsfiddle is an approximation. If you could help, I'd enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems in your solution:

- you should split on `', '` in stead of `','`
- var `foundId = ids[index];` -> should be `ids.split(', ')[index];`

[Working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/d7CCr/):

```
function checkSelected() {
    var ids = "9, 133";
    var idsArr = ids.split(", ");
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('gridCheck');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; 
        var index = idsArr.indexOf(checkboxes[i].
        if (index >= 0) {
            var foundId = idsArr[index];
            if (checkboxes[i].value == foundId) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Though I think it would be better to trim the id values rather than depend on the separator to always have exactly one space after the comma.

Comment: I'd do instead `.split(/,\s*/);`